# Templating solution for nested variables using nunjucks or other method

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, template-engine, nunjucks

I have just started using gulp & nunjucks for templating (emails in this case).

I want to solve the problem of calling a module/partial and assigning different values to the attributes each time that it is processed.

It initially seems like a job for a for loop but the module will not necessarily be called upon in sequence within the template

Within the module there are attributes which are assigned to variables. 
I would like to resolve those variables differently depending on the section that the module is being used for.

A very basic example would be - in an index file I'd have :

```
{% block content %}


<!-- logo start -->

{% include genericMod %}

<!-- logo end -->


<!-- some other section start -->

{% include someOtherMod %}

<!-- some other section end -->


<!-- hero start -->

{% include genericMod %}

<!-- hero end -->


{% endblock %}
```

And in the genericMod itself-:

```
<tr>

 <td class="full-width-image" align="{{align}}" ><img src="{{src}}" alt="{{alt}}"/></td>

</tr>
```

The kind of functionality I'd like to tap into would be to define a “modKey” i.e. a variable within each variable in the module
e.g.

```
{{modKey.align}}

{{modKey.src}}

{{modKey.alt}}
```

Then be able to somehow assign that key to the module each time it is called:

```
<!-- logo start —>

{% include genericMod "modKey": "logo" %}

<!-- logo end -->
```

So the above produces:

```
<tr>

 <td class="full-width-image" align="{{logo.align}}" ><img src="{{logo.src}}" alt="{{logo.alt}}"/></td>

</tr>
```

And:

```
<!-- hero start -->

{% include genericMod "modKey": "hero" %}

<!-- hero end -->
```

produces:

```
<tr>

 <td class="full-width-image" align="{{hero.align}}" ><img src="{{hero.src}}" alt="{{hero.alt}}"/></td>

</tr>
```

So that when piped through a json file the respective data would be rendered for each attribute variable:

```
"logo": {
    "alt": "some logo alt text",
    "href": "http://www.someurl.com",
    "align": "left"
  },
 "hero": {
    "alt": "some hero alt text",
    "href": "http://www.someotherurl.com",
    "align": "centre"
  }
```

Obviously that's just a hypothetical solution but is there a way of actually achieving something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the solution is very simple. I had been assigning the value of the context var to a string rather than a variable name when trying to use  'set'.

For the record this works...

```
{% set data = logo %} 
{% include oneIncludeFile %} 
{% set data = hero %} 
{% include otherIncludeFile %}
```

where the include file would be referencing e.g. {{ data.alt }} or {{ data.href }}.

Though a macro might be a better means to achieve this:

```
{% macro foo(data) %} 
<a href="{{ data.href }}"><img src="{{ data.src }}" alt="{{ data.alt }}" /></a> 
{% endmacro %}
```

and then call it like `{{ foo(logo) }}` and `{{ foo(hero) }}` to pass in different sets of data.

Full explanation can be found here: https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/779